# Core data object copying

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I have a subclass on NSManagedObject say Business. I have some Businesses stored in Core Data.
Now I fetch all the businesses from Core Data by

```
 NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
 NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription  entityForName:@"Business" inManagedObjectContext:[Model sharedInstance].managedObjectContext];
 [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

 NSError* error = nil;
 NSMutableArray * businesses = (NSMutableArray*)[self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
 [fetchRequest release];
```

If I want to have a copy of any, one business object, I do :

```
Business *tempBusiness = [[businesses objectAtIndex:0] mutableCopy];
```

At this point, i get an error
 "[Business copyWithZone] unrecognized selector"

Why am i getting this error. Or is there any way to create mutable copy of a Core Data object ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make Deep Copy of NSManagedObject in Core Data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800007/how-to-make-deep-copy-of-nsmanagedobject-in-core-data)

Answer (score 3):

First Core Data doesn't have the concept of mutable and immutable objects. You can always mutate the object (within the contraints of the data model).

Second we need to distinguish between an *in memory copy* and a *copy in the database*. An in memory copy would essentially do a `memncpy` of bytes from memory address A to memory address B. This is essentially what the `copy` and `mutableCopy` provide for us in Objective-C. A *copy in the database* would create a copy of an existing row. The important difference between these types of copies is that the first would not create a duplicate in the database.

In short you cannot do in memory copies of NSManagedObjects. An `NSManagedObject` (in this case Business) is a row in the database. As a result if `copy` and `mutableCopy` worked on `NSManagedObjects` it would create multiple objects referencing the same row in the database from the same `NSManagedObjectContext`. This doesn't make a lot of sense and would create more problems than it solves. For example if you had two copies of a NSManagedObject and you change the name to `@"Bar"` for the first and `@"Foo"` for the second. And then call `save` on your `NSManagedObjectContext` which value be written `@"Foo"` or `@"Bar"`?

In order to create a *copy in the database* you'll need to create a new instance of Business and copy over all the properties and relationships and save the new object.